# C++: The choices of initializing a member class with no implicit default constructor (more constraints in question body)

Tags: c++, object, idioms

`boost::posix_time::time_duration` has three constructor overloads, and no implicit constructor. I need to make some calculations in a class which has some `time_duration` members before I can initialize them. All of this implies that without a default constructor I do not have the luxury of preparing input for my class members in my composing class constructor.

The pattern might be described as follows (which is eroneous):

```
class X {
public:
    x(int i,int j){}
};

class Y {
  x _x; 
public:
    y() {i = 1+1; j=1-1; _x(i,j);}
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I would like some relevant ways of constructing Y (with motivation), where

1. X does not have a default constructor.
2. X cannot be altered directly (but can be subclassed).
3. The generated code is deterministic (no unnecesary expensive constructs malloc/vtables etc).
4. **crucial point** The class Y has *n* X members and *m* possible calculations. Where *n* >1 and *m* > 1. So elegance is important.
5. Unit testing considerations are important.

At this point I am leaning towards either subclassing , or calling functions to do the calculations and calling these functions in the initialization list (if that is even possible). You can comment on these approaches :D.

Comment: Is `time_duration` assignable? The version I have installed is both default-constructible and assignable, but is kind of old. If it's assignable, and you don't want to calculate the correct value in the initializer list, then just initialize it to some dummy value like `seconds(0)`, and assign the correct value in the constructor. If you're calculating multiple durations from multiple inputs, then doing it all in functions called from the initializer list might result in some duplicated work, so reasonable to avoid that.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but isn't [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) a solution to your problem ? That's probably the best way to achieve a default uninitialized state without going for pointers and dynamic allocation.

However, although that would work, it's probably not ideal. My solution of choice would probably be, if possible, to move the calculations in free functions in an anonymous namespace :

```
namespace {
    x computeX()
    {
        int i, j = /* ... */;
        return x(i, j);
    }
}

y::y()
  : _x(computeX())
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Indeed (+1) That hit me when I was driving to work today :D. I'm not familiar with the details, AFAIK optional will enlarge the composing class -- at least if it uses a variable for state, no ?

Comment: @Hassan: yes, there is an additional boolean in each `boost::optional`